# phonegap create not working

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, cordova

I installed node.js on my ubuntu 14.04 using `sudo apt-get install nodejs` then I installed npm using `sudo apt-get install npm` then I tried to install phonegap using npm `install -g phonegap` everything seemed fine but when I try to phonegap create test nothing happens, It just returns non zero that is error but doesn't display any error. I did exactly how it told me to, still no luck! Can any one tell what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reply with an output of the following commands:

```
node --version
npm --version
```

Comment: `node --version` doesn't show anything where as `nodejs --version` gives `v0.10.25` and `npm --version` gives `1.3.10`

Comment: seems like I installed `apt-get install node` earlier in some day so the node command was conflicting, remove the package node, then reinstall nodejs then install npm then phonegap and installs correctly....